# how to stop execution of following steps if a preceding step fails in Jbehave

Tags: bdd, jbehave

I have the below example in JBehave

```
Given user is super user
Given user is active
When user buys 10 items
Then apply 10% discount
```

When execution comes to verify if the user is active (in my example, user is not active), I want the execution stop and report to be generated as failed scenario. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You use Assert:

```
@Given("user is active")
public void givenUserIsActive() {
    Assert.AssertTrue(UserIsActive); // whatever you need to do to test the condition
}
```

I don't have my eclipse loaded, so I don't know the exact include file, but for JUnit, I -think- it's org.junit.assert.  If you're using TestNG it would be different, and the syntax might be different as well.